# Is there a way to get a event fired when delete is pressed when an entry is empty in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, textchanged, xamarin.forms.entry

So i have four different entries, which acts as a pin input holder, and what i'm trying to do is , basically each entry when backspace is pressed should go to the previous entry considering the entry on which the backspace was pressed is empty.

I tried doing it in Renderer but it doesn't fire anything when its empty, same goes for TextChanged

What i was trying to do was a small hack ,where in i tried to put " ", that is a space in all the entries while initializing, and when a user tried to put something i would check the old value and new value, and replace it, but the problem seems to be when i navigate to the second entry and lets say i press backspace, then the i should be able to go the first entry which is something i'm not able to figure out how

below is a small snippet of what i was trying to do, but it has some issues, any inputs would be helpful

```
private void secondEntry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.OldTextValue == null && !e.NewTextValue.Equals(" "))
            {
                Entry_Second.Text = e.NewTextValue;
                Entry_Third.Focus();
            }
            else if (e.NewTextValue == "")
            {
                Entry_Second.Text = " ";
            }
            else
            {
                Entry_Second.Focus();
            }
}
```

Comment: I can't find any way to detect the delete key when the Entry is empty. Not even in native iOS, i.e. not even for a UITextField. There is a feature request to add this functionality (detect key presses): https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3444

Comment: @jgoldberger-MSFT good to have you reply back again on one of my threads :), is there any way to achieve this ??

Comment: On iOS, I could not find a way because I could find no way to handle key presses in iOS period, so even using a custom renderer I could not get the key press events on iOS. iOS does not seem to send key press events, only text changed events for text fields. It may be possible on Android using a custom renderer, but I would have to look into it. It should definitely be possible on UWP using a custom renderer.This lack of an iOS provided key press event is going to make it very difficult if not impossible for Xamarin.Forms to implement a key press observer on all platforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Xamarin.Android , you can try to handle the edit text key press event. Keycode is Keycode.Back when the delete button is pressed on a keyboard and handle the event accordingly.

```
          editText.KeyPress += (object sender, View.KeyEventArgs e) => {
                e.Handled = false;
                if (e.Event.Action == KeyEventActions.Down && e.KeyCode == Keycode.Back)
                {
                    //your logic here
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            };
```

In Xamarin.iOS

You can try overriding the DeleteBackward method in the custom text field (BackDeleteEventTextField) and call a custom event OnDeleteBackwardKeyPressed.

In the custom renderer you can override the text field with your custom text field in on element changed method

```
   var textField = new BackDeleteEventTextField();
```

and handle the custom event OnDeleteBackwardKeyPressed

```
textField.OnDeleteBackwardKeyPressed += (sender, a) =>
        {
           //handle the back key pressed event
        };
```

In Xamarin.Android :

In the custom renderer you can handle the key press event and look for the Keycode.Back

```
((EditText)this.Control).KeyPress += (object sender, View.KeyEventArgs even) => { 
        even.Handled = false; 
       if (even.Event.Action == KeyEventActions.Down && even.KeyCode ==         Keycode.Back) 
       { 
          //your logic here even.Handled = true;
        }
```

};

**Update**

Elaborating for xamarin.iOS using forms.

Step 1:
Create a custom entry class and create a delegate to handle the back button press

```
public class CustomEntry: Entry
{
    public delegate void BackButtonPressEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

    public event BackButtonPressEventHandler OnBackButton;

    public CustomEntry() { }

    public void OnBackButtonPress() 
    {
        if (OnBackButton!= null)
        {
            OnBackButton(null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Step 2 :Within the custom renderer namespace , create a custom text field class.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEntry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
namespace Origination.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class CustomTextField: UITextField
    {
    }
}
```

Step 3: Within the custom text field, create a event and delegate to handle the delete button click.

```
 public class CustomTextField: UITextField
    {
        // A delegate type for hooking up change notifications.
        public delegate void DeleteBackwardKeyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

        // An event that clients can use to be notified whenever the
        // elements of the list change.
        public event DeleteBackwardKeyEventHandler OnDeleteBackwardKey;


        public void OnDeleteBackwardKeyPressed()
        {
            if (OnDeleteBackwardKey != null)
            {
                OnDeleteBackwardKey(null, null);
            }
        }

        public override void DeleteBackward()
        {
            base.DeleteBackward();
            OnDeleteBackwardKeyPressed();
        }
}
```

Step 4 :Within the custom renderer name space, Create custom renderer class.

```
 public class CustomEntryRenderer: EntryRenderer, IUITextFieldDelegate
 {
 }
```

Step 5:Within the custom renderer's OnElementChanged method create a text field of the custom text field type.

Step 6: Handle the custom text field delete event by passing it to the custom entry back button event handler.

Step 7: Assign the custom text field object to native control.

```
 protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
            {
                if (Element == null) 
                {
                    return;
                }

                var entry = (CustomEntry)Element;
                var textField = new CustomTextField();

               textField.EditingChanged += OnEditingChanged;
                textField.OnDeleteBackwardKey += (sender, a) =>
                {
                    entry.OnBackButtonPress();
                };

                SetNativeControl(textField);

                base.OnElementChanged(e);
            }
```

step 8 : Add the editing changed handler

```
  IElementController ElementController => Element as IElementController;

 void OnEditingChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(Entry.TextProperty, Control.Text);
        }
```

Comment: its possible in Xamarin.Android, i understand that, but i'm not sure if its possible in Xamarin.forms

Comment: Here's a little additional information: Each key press is described by a sequence of key events. A key press starts with a key event with KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN. If the key is held sufficiently long that it repeats, then the initial down is followed additional key events with KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN. The last key event is a KeyEvent.ACTION_UP for the key up. If the key press is canceled, the key up event will have the KeyEvent.FLAG_CANCELED flag set.

Comment: In Xamarin.Forms you can use a custom renderer and use this  ((EditText)this.Control).KeyPress += (object sender, View.KeyEventArgs even) => {
                    even.Handled = false;
                    if (even.Event.Action == KeyEventActions.Down && even.KeyCode == Keycode.Back)
                    {
                        //your logic here
                        even.Handled = true;
                    }
                };

Comment: What about iOS, what would be the native equivalent for that ??

Comment: was able to get that running on Android, but the events are hitting twice when i press delete, that is it deletes two characters

Comment: You can try adding the the event handler within a method [BackKeyPressedMethod(object o,KeyEventArgs e)].. and deregister and register the events textField.OnDeleteBackwardKeyPressed -= BackKeyPressedMethod; textField.OnDeleteBackwardKeyPressed += BackKeyPressedMethod;

Comment: Could you let me know again how this can be done in iOS ??

Comment: Do you mean xamarin.ios or native iOS??

Comment: Xamarin.iOS is there in the updated answer , do you want me to elaborate??

Comment: @pooja thanks a lot for your continued support, sorry to bother you again, it seems to be hitting backspace now, but the textchange event for forms doesn't seem to work anymore,is there any way to do this in the native control or forms element ??

Comment: You will have to add  textField.EditingChanged += OnEditingChanged; in on element changed and follow the step 8 in the updated answer

Comment: @pooja, works perfectly thanks a lot, I've created BindableProperty for MaxLength,IsPassword and Placeholder, IsPassword and Placeholder are getting perfectly reflected, but not the MaxLength, should i do something with the native control

Answer (score 0):

In order to validate if the string is empty you can just:

```
(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
```

After that, is just a matter of focus and unfocus the Entries that you require.

Comment: validation is fine, but i'm not able to get the event itself when its empty

Answer (score 0):

I found the first example for Xamarin.Android in the accepted answer worked for me with the exception of changing `KeyCode.Back` to `KeyCode.Del` to capture the backspace keypress.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30993469)

Comment: Thank you for the correction, @LordWilmore. As soon as I get enough reputation I will change this "Answer" to a comment.