# Is there any event handler by MAUI for hooking delete button click?

Tags: .net, maui, maui-community-toolkit, maui-android

Is there a way that I can hook delete button event in MAUI for Android and iOS.
If not, can someone share an example of a Handler that do the same?

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you give some context? Can't you just subscribe to the `TextChanged` or `Completed` events of the input control (e.g. an *Entry*) and act on that? Directly subscribing to key press events is a finicky thing.

Comment: @Julian I simulate entering 6 digit code with `TextChanged` event and `Focus` I jump from one entry to another and also when I got an number entered with delete It Focus on the previous Entry. The problem is when I for ex. fill first entry and on second entry I see that I filled wrong number on first entry and in that case I want with just pressing delete to focus on the first entry. The problem is there is no value on second entry and TextChanged event is not hit. Sorry for the long explanation maybe you can't catch my point :(

Comment: It would be helpful to add that information to the question. I haven't tried something like that yet. It should technically be possible using handlers, since it's also possible to do this directly on Android with Java. You'll probably need to modify the MainActivity.

Comment: This might help [Is there a way to get a event fired when delete is pressed when an entry is empty in xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54169553/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-event-fired-when-delete-is-pressed-when-an-entry-is-empt)